# Delete or ignore I/O from a schematic block in Lattice?

Tags: vhdl, schematics, clock, lattice

I am programming with a Lattice ispMACH 4000ZE Pico DevKit and with the software ispLEVER Classic Project Navigator. I want to use in my schematic file the OSCTIMER block from the Lattice library, but the problem is, that I MUST use all inputs and output, even though I only need one output and one input. How can I ignore the other pins? If I cannot ignore them, how can I delete them? I tried by editing the symbol (I deleted the input and output pins I did not need) but it did not work.

I compile it without problems but when I open the Contraint Editor, this error appears:

```
Fatal Error 3501: Instance name I26/N_8 cannot be resolvedDone: failed with exit code: 0002.
```

Thanks again.

**EDIT: Oct. 10**
So I programmed the clock with VHDL like the documentation showed me:
[Advance Features](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/Documents/ApplicationNotes/AD/AdvancedFeaturesoftheispMACH4000ZEFamily.PDF?document_id=29135)

```
--Libraries 
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

library lattice;
use lattice.components.all;

library MACH;
use MACH.components.all;

entity Int_Clock is

port( 
    CLOCK_OUT : out std_logic);
end;

architecture structural of Int_Clock is

component osctimer
generic(TIMER_DIV : string);

port(   DYNOSCDIS : in std_logic; -- Disable internal oscillator
        TIMERRES : in std_logic;  -- Reset timer
        OSCOUT : out std_logic;   -- Oscillator output
        TIMEROUT : out std_logic); -- Timer output
end component;

signal tmr_out, osc_dis, tmr_rst, osc_out : std_logic; 

begin

I1: OSCTIMER
generic map (TIMER_DIV => "128")

port map (  DYNOSCDIS => osc_dis,
        TIMERRES => tmr_rst,
        OSCOUT => osc_out,
        TIMEROUT => tmr_out);

CLOCK_OUT <= tmr_out; 

end structural;
```

Again, it compiled without any problems BUT when I wanted to make my JEDEC-File an error appeared:

> lpffll.exe stopped working

What does this even mean?! ispLever did not stop working, it actually made my JEDEC-File (I think) but my clock still does not work (I am monitoring it with a oscilloscope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete IO from a block, but ignore them. Some warnings may appear, but sometimes they are not important (always check!). The best solution is to program your own block and select the signals you want to use.

The error with my clock was, that I did not placed it in the main schematic. So everything was fine until I tried to download it to my target system. Always put the clock in your main schematic part. Check the hierarchy diagram so you know what is the main part.